# Selecting a class of radio button inside a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery to display some forms depending on user input. I have a basic info to fill and then the user select radio buttons that will show one distinct form depending on the input (four radio buttons, 2 questions). The problem is that I don't know how to choose it, I want two distint functions for each question.

My Jquery code (just the idea of what I want):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('form[name="THE_FORM"]'.find('p.ISVM')).click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "1") {
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#second').show();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "2") {
        $('#first').show();
        $('#second').hide();
    }
 });

    $('form[name="THE_FORM"]'.find('p.ISVH').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "3") {
        $('#third').hide();
        $('#fourth').show();
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "4") {
        $('#third').show();
        $('#fourth').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
   <form name="The_FORM">
         <p class = "ISVH"> <span> Is Virtual host? </span>
            <label for="VH"> Yes <input id="VH" type="radio" name="VH" value="3"> </label>
            <label for="NVH"> No <input id="NVH" type="radio" name="VH" value="4"> </label> </p>

        <p class = "ISVM"> <span> Is Virtual Machine? </span>
            <label for="VM"> Yes <input id="VM" type="radio" name="VM" value="1"> </label>
            <label for="PM"> No <input id="PM" type="radio" name="VM" value="2"> </label> </p>

 ...divs first, second, third, fourth here...
     </form>
 </div>
```

I tried:

```
  $('form[name="THE_FORM"]'.find('p.ISVM')).click(function () ...
  $('form[name="THE_FORM"]: p.ISVM')).click(function () ...
```

Bit is not working..
What I am doing wrong here? How I write the jquery functions to select the what I want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form[name="THE_FORM"]'.find('p.ISVM')).click(function () ...
```

should be

```
$('form[name="THE_FORM"]').find('p.ISVM').click(function () ...
```

while

```
$('form[name="THE_FORM"]: p.ISVM')).click(function () ...
```

should be

```
$('form[name="THE_FORM"] p.ISVM')).click(function () ...
```

Also, using `name` attribute is not as efficient as using an ID:

and then one of these would be my preference:

```
$('#THE_FORM').find('p.ISVM').click(function () ...
$('#THE_FORM p.ISVM').click(function () ...
```

or even

```
$('#THE_FORM').on('click', 'p.ISVM', function () ...
```

which does something else, but that something else is nice.

Even better, I'd probably disregard `click` and go directly for `change` event on `input`s.

Comment: Hi Amadan, and thank for your reply. Nevertheless, I am trying to use your first two suggestions, and they are not working for me... Can you write some code for me so that I can see it running ( like in JSfiddle for example) It will be really appreciated. I dont see where is my error...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(input[name*='VH']).change()
 {
      var vh= $(input[name*='VH']).val();

      if (vh == 1 )
      {
          $('#first').hide();
          $('#second').show();
      } else if (vh == 2) 
      {
          $('#first').show();
          $('#second').hide();
      }
 }

 $(input[name*='VM']).change(){
      var vm = $(input[name*='VM']).val();

      if (vm == 1 )
      {
          $('#third').hide();
          $('#fourth').show();
      } else if (vh == 2) 
      {
          $('#fourth').hide();
          $('#third').show();
      }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. How do you use it with the document ready function? one has to do $(input[name*='VM']).change( function {... ?? Looks like is not working for me :/

Comment: You put the code above inside document ready function. Instead of name*='VM' you can use name='VM'. All DOM elements with name attribute equal xxxx will be monitored.